# How to run multiple cURL commands simultaneously?

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, curl, ckan

I want to run multiple cURL commands simultaneously (examples of the commands are below). What's the best way of doing this? Can it be done as a .bat?

```
curl -H "authorization:apikey" https://ckan/data/api/action/resource_update -v --form id="resource1" --form upload=@"dataset1.csv"
curl -H "authorization:apikey" https://ckan/data/api/action/resource_update -v --form id="resource2" --form upload=@"dataset2.csv"
curl -H "authorization:apikey" https://ckan/data/api/action/resource_update -v --form id="resource3" --form upload=@"dataset3.csv"
curl -H "authorization:apikey" https://ckan/data/api/action/resource_update -v --form id="resource4" --form upload=@"dataset4.csv"
```

Comment: Answered on SuperUser: [How to: concurrent cURL downloads?](https://superuser.com/questions/1244659/how-to-concurrent-curl-downloads)

Comment: @OP `Can it be done as a .bat` => I suppose it's a `.bat`, not a bash shell script `.sh`?

Comment: use the [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)  command to start an independent process.

Comment: [Execute curl requests in parallel in bash](https://serverfault.com/questions/456490/execute-curl-requests-in-parallel-in-bash)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just kick them off in background?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did it as shell script which worked well